# redirecting several domains to one in .htaccess

Tags: url, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to add some code to my .htaccess to redirect several different domains to a single domain. I have seen code that will do this for one domain such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```

But what is the best approach to have multiple domains redirected to a single domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only redirect if the domain is *not* the one you want to redirect to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www\.example\.com$)  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```