# htaccess direct domain and subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem where I want to redirect all traffic [301 permanent] from

```
www.example.com --> www.website2.com
blog.example.com --> blog.example.com
```

So redirect all domains/subdomains on "Example.com" to website2.com EXCEPT for the blog on example.com ? Little unsure how to set this up using .htaccess on "example.com" ?

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760601/redirecting-several-domains-to-one-in-htaccess):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^blog\.example\.com$)  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website2.com/$1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```

Line by line:

In case the `Host:` header ("%{HTTP_HOST}") is *not* ("!") `blog.example.com` (no other string matches that regex), execute the following rewrite:

for a pattern matching anything (".*", that is, for any URL), redirect to the same path on www.website2.com (e.g. http://blahblah.example.com/somepath will get redirected to http://www.website2.com/somepath ).

Comment: thanks a lot - so this takes the reverse approach ? redirect everything BUT blog.example.com ?

Comment: hmm - the only problem with this code is that it doesn't allow for blog.example.com/post-name/ etc ? how to fix this i.e. so it allows for any url on blog.example.com but redirects everything else not on this subdomain ?

Comment: @Tom: Have you tried this, or is this just your speculation? The code will *not* do anything for URLs on blog.example.com, as the second line won't be reached (because the RewriteCond will evaluate to false).

Comment: hey piskvor - yeah I tried it a few times. the problem is for example - when i try blog.example.com/wp-admin - it attempts to find http://www.website2.com/wp-admin ? but I basically need anything on the blog.example.com to remain valid - so i.e. blog.example.com/wp-admin or blog.example.com/post-name/ etc and everything else to redirect to website2.com ?

Comment: @Tom: That is strange. Is it really *this* rule causing the redirection? Also, some browsers cache the *permanent* redirection pages, so you could be seeing responses that the server used to send, sometime in the past. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @Tom: Most likely, have tested this exact setup here and works as expected. I'm glad that it helped :)